# Why is it impossible to explicitly default a copy constructor with volatile argument?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, copy-constructor, volatile

I could not find where in the standard it is stated that it is forbidden to explicitly default a copy-constructor and copy-assignment with a `volatile&` or `const volatile&` argument, like this:

```
struct A{
   A(const volatile A&) =default; // fails to compile on (all) compilers
   };
```

In [dcl.fct.def.default] there is no such a restriction, while [class.copy] specifies that `A(const volatile A&)` is a copy constructor.

Note: I am just looking for the location in the text of the standard which specifies this behavior.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are in the right sections, but are overlooking some crucial bullets.

[[dcl.fct.def.default]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.default#1):

> A function definition of the form:
>
> ...
>
> is called an *explicitly-defaulted* definition. A function that is
>   explicitly defaulted shall
>
> - **have the same declared function type** (except for possibly differing ref-qualifiers and except that in the case of a copy
>     constructor or copy assignment operator, **the parameter type may be
>     “reference to non-const T”, where T is the name of the member
>     function's class**) **as if it had been implicitly declared**, and

[[class.copy.ctor]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.copy.ctor#7):

> The implicitly-declared copy constructor for a class X will have the
>   form
>
> ```
> X::X(const X&)
> ```
>
> if each potentially constructed subobject of a class type M (or array
>   thereof) has a copy constructor whose first parameter is of type const
>   M& or const volatile M&.<sup>**119**</sup> Otherwise, the implicitly-declared copy
>   constructor will have the form
>
> ```
> X::X(X&)
> ```
>
> ...
>   <sub>119) This implies that the reference parameter of the implicitly-declared copy constructor cannot bind to a volatile lvalue;</sub>

When the above is summed up, your only two options for explicitly defaulting a copy c'tor are these:

```
struct A {
   A(const A&) = default;
};

struct B {
   B(B&) = default;
};
```

When the standard says `A(const volatile A&)` is a copy constructor. It means that a *user-provided* c'tor with such a parameter can be the classes copy c'tor.